# I get LNK1169 and LNK2005 no matter what i do

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors

i am making a program regarding bunnies and linked lists. I have five files: `link.h, link.cpp, bunny.h, bunny.cpp, main.cpp`

> When i try to compile my program (Using MVS2013) i get two errors;
>   LNK1169: Error  3   error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
>   and 
>   LNK2005: Error  2   error LNK2005: "struct node * curr" (?curr@@3PAUnode@@A) already defined in list.obj

I have no idea where the error lies, so i did some research and found out these errors mean that i have defined something more than once, but i cant find out where. I tried moving all #includes to one file but that didn't help either.

I have scanned my code but cant find anywhere that fits this error, so now i'm stumped.

NB! Before you get mad at me for posting a giant wall of text, i don't know where the error lies, so i thought it was best to include it all

bunny.h

```
#ifndef BUNNY_H
#define BUNNY_H

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class bunny
{
    private:

        int m_age;
        char m_gender;
        bool m_radioactiveVampire;
        string m_color;
        string m_name;

    public: 
        bunny();
        void setRadioactiveVampire(bool RV) {m_radioactiveVampire = RV; }

        string getName(void) { return m_name; }
        string getColor(void) { return m_color; }
        bool getRadioactiveVampire(void) { return m_radioactiveVampire; }
        char getGender(void) { return m_gender; }
        int getAge(void) { return m_age; }
};
#endif
```

bunny.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

/* 16 bunnies */ string maleBunnies[] = { "Abel", "Abraham", "Ace", "Acer", "Achilles", "Acker", "Adagio", "Admiral", "Aesop", "Ajax", "Aladdin", "Alaska", "Albert", "Alchemy", "Alex", "Mark" };
/* 16 bunnies */ string femaleBunnies[] = { "Abba", "Aberdeen", "Abigail", "Acura", "Adele", "Adoni", "Aki", "Alibi", "Alice", "Amaretto", "Amaya", "Ambrosia", "Amore", "Amorette", "Anabell", "Anastasia" };
/* 8  colors  */ string bunnyColors[] = { "Red", "Black", "Yellow", "Gray", "Green", "White", "Blue", "Purple" };

bunny::bunny()
{
    m_age = 0;
    m_color = bunnyColors[rand() % 8 + 1];

    if (rand() % 2 + 1 == 1) //calculates what gender and name respectively
    {
        m_gender = 'f';
        m_name = femaleBunnies[rand() % 16 + 1]; 
    }
    else if (rand() % 2 + 1 == 2)
    {
        m_gender = 'm';
        m_name = maleBunnies[rand() % 16 + 1]; 
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Uh oh, something went wrong with gender generation";
    }

    if (rand() % 100 + 1 < 2) //calculates 2% chance on radioactive vampire
    {
        m_radioactiveVampire = true; 
    }
    else if (rand() % 100 + 1 > 2)
    {
        m_radioactiveVampire = false; 
    }
    else
    {
        cerr << "Uh oh, something went wrong with RV calculation ";
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctime>

using namespace std; 

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    bunnyList list;
    bunny *b;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        b = new bunny();

        list.addBunny(b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

list.h

```
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

#include "bunny.h"
#include "stdafx.h"

typedef struct node
{
    node *next;
    bunny *data;
} *nodePtr;

nodePtr curr = NULL;

class bunnyList
{
    private:

    public:
        node *head; 

        bunnyList();
        void displayAllBunnies(void);
        void addBunny(bunny *b); // linked list stuff
        void removeBunny(int bunnyNumber); // linked list stuff
};

#endif
```

and last list.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

bunnyList::bunnyList()
{
}

void bunnyList::addBunny(bunny *b)
{
    node *newNode = new node; //creates a node and holds its pointer
    newNode->data = b;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}


void bunnyList::displayAllBunnies(void)
{
    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

(list.h and bunny.h is included in stdafx.h, this was one solution that didnt help, but they are there)

Comment: also I think you are not supposed to have stdafx.h in the header file. The compiler ignores everything before that line, which will cause problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining variables in the `list.h`

`nodePtr curr = NULL;`

When inserting the `.h` in multiple translation units, the compiler report the same symbol define in the translation units.

Move the variable for the `.cpp` if you need to use the variable in multiple translation units, use [`extern`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433204/how-do-i-use-extern-to-share-variables-between-source-files-in-c) (linked a post with more info about extern).

Reading the code, there's no necessity of declaring `curr` as a free variable, it's only used in `displayAllBunnies` as an iteration variable (that could be local).

Change displayAllBunnies to:

```
void bunnyList::displayAllBunnies(void) {
    nodePtr curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL) {
        cout << curr->data << endl;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
}
```

And remove line: `nodePtr curr = NULL;` from `list.h`

Comment: Moved it to list.cpp instead, fixed the issue, thank you. I see what you mean in the last sentence